# Quier actualizar a la fecha mas cercana de hoy en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero restar Stock de los productos dependiendo si la fecha esta cercana a la de hoy,pero no me funciona.

```
   update tableDate set cantidad=cantidad-[xcantidad]
       where id_producto=[xcodpro] and (tableDate > now)limit 1 ;
```

Comment: Y... cual es el problema? Por favor, una respuesta más elaborada que "no me funciona", o "no me da", o "me da error". Recuerda proveer un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: now es una funcion debes ejecutarla con `()` osea now() eso te da la fecha de hoy, por otra parte si quieres obtener una fecha relativa a hoy, osea ayer o 3 dias atras debes usar date_sub(), Ejemplo: SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 DAY);